# innerHTML, innerText and textContent only return the first word out of a text

Tags: javascript

I want to select a text from a div using the simplest function ever. The problem is that I only get the first word of the text. I want the whole text, which in this case it's only two words.

```js
var text = '';
function spanTitle() {
    let title = document.querySelector('title');
    text = title.innerHTML;
}

spanTitle();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="title">Bottega Ricci</div>
```

I have used `text = title.innerHTML;`, `text = title.innerText;`and `text = title.textContent;`. Every one of these only return the first word `Bottega`.

Shouldn't it return the whole text ?

Comment: The code reads the title of the page,

Answer (score 4):

Your code works if you use the proper class selector in `querySelector`: `.title`.

Here's an updated version of your code that might help you. It returns the title value from the function rather than relying on a global variable.

```js
function spanTitle() {
  const title = document.querySelector('.title');
  return title.textContent;
}

console.log(spanTitle());
```

```html
<div class="title">Bottega Ricci</div>
```

Comment: OP mentioned *Every one of these only return the first word Bottega* which suggest that was typo in his code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why that's happening. I tested the OP's code and it works so long as the selector is correct.

Comment: I have been raging over this for the past 15 minutes. I knew it was because of a stupid little mistake, but I couldn't find it even if my life depended on it. Thanks man, you've just saved my keyboard's life.

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica, why did you write *Every one of these only return the first word Bottega*?

Comment: @Mamun because every one of those returned `Bottega` in the log.

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica, no it will not, it will give you an error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null*

Comment: @Mamun no, it won't, because it returns whatever is inside the `<title>` tag, which in this case is `<title>Bottega</title>` I did not include the whole HTML code because it did not seem relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a `<title>` element on the page with the content set to `Bottega`.
Your selector is selecting an element like this: `<title></title>`.
You want to select the element with the class `title`, to do add a dot in front of the classname: `.title`.

Example:

```js
var text = '';
function spanTitle() {
    let title = document.querySelector('.title');
    text = title.innerHTML;
}

spanTitle();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="title">Bottega Ricci</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing the dot(**.**) on the query selector

```js
let text = '';
function spanTitle() {
    let title = document.querySelector('.title');
    text = title.innerHTML;
}

spanTitle();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="title">Bottega Ricci</div>
```

for [style] class use dot(**.**)

for id use #

for tag use withou anything: html, body, div, title

Comment: I know, I know... it was a typo that I did not catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = '';
function spanTitle() {
    let title = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
    text = title[0].innerHTML;
}

spanTitle();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="title">Bottega Ricci</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to select the first element of `title`. I want the whole thing !